# Twitter API GET user_timeline reply/comment count

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, spring-social, spring-social-twitter

Is there any way to get the comment/reply count for a tweet using GET statuses/user_timeline in addition to favorite_count and retweet_count which are already returned?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This feature had been requested since 2011 but there are no public API for reply counts so far, so it's not possible to directly get the reply count of a tweet.

---

But there exists a workaround using the [Search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets):

You can do the query: `q = "to:{author_screen_name}", sinceId = {tweet_id}`, while `author_screen_name` is the screen name (like 'shiftpsh' in @shiftpsh) and `tweet_id` is id of the tweet you're trying to get the reply count.

Loop through all the tweets in the results and filter which `in_reply_to_status_id_str` is `{tweet_id}`.

Keep in mind that the Standard Search API has a search index limit of 7 days (30 days if premium) so the resulting reply count can be not accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter still doesn't have a sound solution for this.

Similar to shiftpsh's answer, with Node you can make a query to `https://twitter.com/${screen_name}/status/${tweet_id}` and use a module like JSDOM in JavaScript to parse the HTML into a DOM object. With that object, you can use normal document querying functions to pull out the reply count (and many other data points).

```
var repliesCount = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("permalink-tweet-container")[0]
    .getElementsByClassName("ProfileTweet-action--reply")[0]
  .getElementsByClassName("ProfileTweet-actionCount")[0]
  .getAttribute("data-tweet-stat-count"));
```

This solution is a form of web scraping, so please be responsible when employing these types of solutions.

EDIT: Just noticed your tags are for Java, [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) is a great library for parsing HTML to an object and traversing it with jQuery like methods.

Comment: Note that scraping Twitter website is illegal due to their user agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd update this answer for anyone who's facing the issue.
Twitter's API now includes ["metrics" endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/tweet-metrics/api-reference/get-tweets-metrics) where you can get this information.

Following the documentation:

"GET /tweets/metrics/private supports the ability to retrieve Tweet engagement data and delivers the following metrics:

- impressions
- Retweets
- Quote Tweets
- likes
- replies
- video views
- video view quartiles
  "

The caveat, however, is that it only applies to owned or authorised accounts and tweets posted in the previous 30 days (before the request)